# Kusto Query Language - Microsoft Defender IP Subnet Query

Tags: kql, microsoft365-defender

Is there a way to query for IP ranges from the DeviceEvent table using IP subnet notation i.e. 1.1.1.0/24 vs. listing individual IPs 1.1.1.1?

Instead of list inididual IPs for

```
| where LocalIP == "1.1.1.1"
```

I would like to list subnet range "1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.255" or "1.1.1.0/24"

Comment: It's `1.1.1.*0* - 1.1.1.255`

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(LocalIP:string)["1.1.0.255", "1.1.1.0", "1.1.1.179", "1.1.1.255", "1.129.13.42", "2.0.0.0"]
| where ipv4_is_in_range(LocalIP, "1.1.1.0/24")
```

| LocalIP |
| --- |
| 1.1.1.0 |
| 1.1.1.179 |
| 1.1.1.255 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDZ/85MQczwCr4pKizLx0zWglQz1DPQM9I1NTJR0FMAfIRTANzS0RHIQiI0s9Q2M9EyMQ1wioHQiVYnm5ahTKM1KLUhUyC8pM4jOL4zPz4osS89LhtiJs0DcyUdIEAMdz2GOWAAAA)